# Program type already present: com.folder.servicehelper.BuildConfig

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an Android library. So, I have a module that will be the .aar file.

This is the Graddle file of this module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28



defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation (name:'offending_library_2.0.0', ext:'aar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Aside, I have another module (app module) which I use to test this library, asa  dummy app. I have that library loaded here too, since if I don`t have it it will not compile, This is the Graddle of the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.company.domain"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
implementation 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation (name:'offending_library_2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation project (':arcgislibrary')<----- This is the other module
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This way, I am having the error Program type already present: com.folder.servicehelper.BuildConfig
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.folder.servicehelper.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

The BuildConfig class is inside the offending_library of my graddle files.

I tried to delete the .aar file of the libs folder of the app module, but that way it doesn't compiles. Tried to do

```
implementation (name:'offending_library_2.0.0', ext:'aar'){
    exclude group:'com.folder.servicehelper'
}
```

but the result is the same.

Any idea of how could I get rid of that error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that there are two `BuildConfig` included, comes from the `AAR` being referenced twice:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation (name:'offending_library_2.0.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

when only including `['*.jar']`, this should be resolved.

to nevertheless include the `AAR`, one can define the `libs` directory as flat [repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir { dirs "libs" }
    }
}
```

and then use this syntax in the module-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.my.company.domain:offending_library:2.0.0@aar"
}
```

the documentation: [Managing Transitive Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html).

Comment: It's working! This did the trick, despite I am not adding any reference to the library in the app module, but if I delete the aar file in the libs folder of the app module, it stops working. So, if I am correct, any developer using my library will need to put the offending library in libs folder, right? I have it now in libs folder of both module and app gradle. How does app module knows that there is a library to be used? Thank you a lot Martin!